# Is there an equivalent of adminconsent in Google?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

A web application implementing **Microsoft OAuth can construct an `adminconsent` login** where the user can then accept the oauth scopes on behalf of their organisation. The result is, subsequent users from the same organisation logging in via oauth will NOT be prompted to accept those scopes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent

**Is there an equivalent mechanism in Google**? Where I can send Google Suite admins a link, they can accept the oauth permissions required on behalf of their organisation, and users from their organisation logging via oauth won't be prompted; they'll just login without disruption

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing would be to configure [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) for the app. As mentioned in the article:

> "In enterprise applications you may want to programmatically access a user's data without any manual authorization on their part". In Google Workspace domains, the domain administrator can grant third-party applications with domain-wide access to its users' data.

I haven't tested it myself to know if by doing it the users will not be prompted to the consent screen, but based on that article it should.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in Google is a Workspace Marketplace app. https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace

When the app is verified (only if certain data access is requested) and some admin installs it for the whole domain or some Org. Units, the OAuth flow does not ask for user consent.

Comment: What arrangement of pieces needs to be in place for this to work?  OAuth is performed by an OAuth client, while marketplace apps (afaik) use domain-wide-delegation as performed by a service account.  The SA and the oauth client aren't related besides existing within the same project, so how does this cause and effect work?

Comment: Note that your app can have multiple Oauth clients for the different ways to authorize apps: web apps with a redirect URL, or installed apps with an implicit flow, and all of them are enabled in the target workspace (check any installed Marketplace app and look at the  OAuth clients tab besides OAuth scopes).  Google can intercept the Oauth flow and bypass the consent screen when the required conditions are met.